# How do I take only the countries names from a geo json file?

Tags: json, geojson

I am trying to take all countries name from a geojson file, but it doesn't seems to work. How should I reach through to get all names and put them into a select tag?
Attaching a small screenshot from the geo json. And do I have to conver it into array to be able to work in js with it? Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp7OD.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? It could help to share more details, such that others know which programming language you are using and how you load the file in general

Comment: this is my code so far:

async function loadCountries() {
  const response = await fetch('countryBorders.geo.json');
  const data = await response.json();
  createCountryList(data.features);}

loadCountries();

function createCountryList(countryNames) {
  document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = 
    `<select>
        <option>choose a country</option>
        ${Object.keys(countryNames).map(function(country) {
          return `<option>${country}</option>`
        }).join('')}
    </select>`
      
}

Comment: I used async await to get the json, and worked fine on the select menu with other json files or external api, but this geo json is intimidating me. At the moment the select dropdown shows me from 0 to 144, those are the numbers of objects  inside the features properties. I am very new to develpment. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing. Also, please add the neccessary tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have your geojson stored in a variable, you can iterate on it :

```js
json['countries'].forEach(country => console.log(country))
```

Considering this synthax, you can resolve your problem with this solution :

```js
name_of_countries = []
your_geojson['features'].forEach(feature => name_of_countries.push(feature['properties']['name']))

console.log(name_of_countries)
```

For your personal need :

```js
const fillCountriesSelect = (dataFeatures) => {
    divCountries = document.getElementById('countries')
    select = "<select>"
    dataFeatures.forEach(feature => {
        select += feature['properties']['name']
    })
    select += "</select>"
    divCountries.innerHTML = select
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can I ask what the "e" in push method stands for?

Comment: Just a typo, sorry. You just have to replace it by *feature*. @K.N.

Comment: yes, I thought so. when logged on the console it gives me "array 175 and just the names of the countries, but cannot figure out why they don't appear when i click on the select dropdown menu. My code:

function createCountryList(dataFeatures) {
  countriesNames = [];

  document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = 
    `<select>
        <option>choose a country</option>
        ${dataFeatures.forEach(feature => `<option>${countriesNames.push(feature['properties']['name'])}</option>`)}
    </select>`

    console.log(countriesNames);
    }

Comment: I have updated my post to answer your question @K.N.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I an very new to this. Lots to learn. Thanks indeed.

Comment: @K.N. Don't hesitate to mark your problem as solved and let an upvote to my post :)